# how does ebp value changes in this function

Tags: assembly, stack, stack-overflow

In main function:

```
 0x08049230 <+0>:   push   %ebp
 0x08049231 <+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
 0x08049233 <+3>:   sub    $0x28,%esp
 0x08049236 <+6>:   movl   $0xdeadbeef,-0xc(%ebp)
 0x0804923d <+13>:  call   0x8048ed4 <getbuf>
 0x08049242 <+18>:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
```

In getbuf function:

```
0x08048ed4 <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048ed5 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048ed7 <+3>:    sub    $0x28,%esp
0x08048eda <+6>:    lea    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x08048edd <+9>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048ee0 <+12>:   call   0x8048de4 <Gets>
0x08048ee5 <+17>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
0x08048eea <+22>:   leave  
0x08048eeb <+23>:   ret
```

Basically main functions use %ebp-0xc to check corrupted stack.

In getbuf functions,  lea -0x14(%ebp),%eax allocates 20 bytes for the input string.

If I provided 24 bytes, $ebp will be overwritten. I am not sure why the change of ebp in getbuf will affect ebp value in main function.

I know that $ebp will push onto the stack. When getbuf returns, $ebp will pop out from the stack. Does $ebp from main function receives $ebp from getbuf?

I also did some tests. My input string is aaaabbbbccccddddeeee, which is 24 bytes. I set it up a break point at  0x08049242 <+18>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx, I print $ebp, however which is not hex representation for eeee. I noticed that the value stored in $ebp indeed changed. If input is less than 20bytes, the value is 0xbffff6c8. If the input is 24 bytes, its value becomes 0xb7fd0ac0.

Can anyone explain how it changes and how does $ebp in main function know the value of $ebp in gebuf function?

Thanks

Comment: Read up on stack frames, e.g https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one copy of the registers (per thread). Function calls and returns do not change registers except for `esp` as required for the return address. The very point of pushing and popping `ebp` is to preserve it for the caller. As such, if you overwrite the saved value on the stack, then a wrong value will be popped back into `ebp` and returned to the caller.

> My input string is `aaaabbbbccccddddeeee`, which is 24 bytes.

No, that's 20 bytes, plus one for the terminating zero. This still overflows the buffer, and should result in the low byte of `ebp` being zeroed. Note that if you use a string of length 24, such as `aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff` that will overwrite `ebp` to `ffff` which is `0x66666666` in hex, but the terminating zero will overwrite the low byte of the return address, so you won't even return to the correct place. You can use a string of length 23 such as `aaaabbbbccccddddeeeefff` in which case your `ebp` should be `0x00666666`:

```
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
aaaabbbbccccddddeeeefff

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
8       mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
(gdb) p/a $ebp
$6 = 0x666666
```